.NET MAUI reader like a book
Goal is to create reader app that will display html content like a book, pages must be swipe able and when text reaches to end on one page it must be continued on another one, and dynamically adapt to font size changes.
Right now html is represented as collecion
public ObservableCollection<string> ParsedChapters { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

and Page calculation work like this
      private void PopulateContent()
        {
            ParsedChapters.Clear();

            double lineHeight = FontSize * 1.2;
            int linesPerPage = (int)(_screenHeight / lineHeight);
            double avgCharWidth = _fontSize * 0.6;
            int charsPerLine = (int)(_sreenWidth / avgCharWidth);
            int charsPerPage = linesPerPage * charsPerLine;
            int totalLength = _bookContent.Length;
            int chunkCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalLength / charsPerPage);
            Pages = chunkCount;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentPageDisplay));

            for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++)
            {
                int start = i * charsPerPage;
                int length = Math.Min(charsPerPage, totalLength - start);
                string chunk = new string(_bookContent.Slice(start, length).ToArray());
                ParsedChapters.Add(chunk);
            }
        }


Problem is that when there are many Line Break tags in html page gets scroll (can't fit on calculated area) and i need to avoid that, either with better calculation or other way to display .xaml page, maybe there is some solution for this kind of rendering?...

 <CarouselView
     x:Name="Carousel"
     IsVisible="False"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ParsedChapters}"
     PositionChanged="Carousel_PositionChanged">
     <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ScrollView>
                 <StackLayout Padding="10">
                     <Label
                         FontSize="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModalReaderViewModel}}, Path=FontSize}"
                         Text="{Binding .}"
                         TextColor="Black"
                         TextType="Html">
                         <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                             <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                         </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                     </Label>
                 </StackLayout>
             </ScrollView>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
 </CarouselView>


Ive tried scrollview with Orientation=Horizontal and many other things but no result

Can you show the effect you got and the expected effect you want about the many Line Break tags?

link
this is what <br> tags from html source are causing, somehow i need to  manage breaking label content when it reaches end of page and continue on next page

when there is not that much <br> tags calculation is correct and label content is fitted on page without scroll

According to the screen recording in the link you provided, due to the setting of <br>, the page does not automatically jump to the next page after sliding to the bottom. Can you provide the code for the TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped event? How does this event achieve page jump?

That event is responsible for overlay animation, check this out link , here page has scroll because half of html included break tags and it messed up my calculations. in second case link there are not that much <br> tags and page looks as it should be, without scroll. I need to manage rendering any html like book pages, without scrolling manner.

Have you tried removing the scrollview tag, which controls whether the page can be scrolled

then half of the content will be hidden

Does this problem only exist on Android platform? Have you tried iOS or Windows?
